# PHP / MySql - Concatenation in query

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I am having problems concatenating a variable to a number (with the variable first, because $info1002 is not a known variable), I appreciate my problem here must be my single double quotations and I've tried a lot of combinations and my googling hasn't helped.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (ID, info1) VALUES ('','.$info.''002')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to format it like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (ID, info1) VALUES ('','".$info."002')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, if you have the `ID` field set to `AutoIncrement`, you can ommit it like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (info1) VALUES ('".$info."002')") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will insert value of $info followed by 002 into the database.

Comment: works +1, personally i like to keep my AI's visible so i remember what the H i'm trying to do! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (ID, info1) VALUES ('','".$info."002"')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you concatenate if before adding it to the query? I think it is much easier so you don't have that mass with quotation.

```
$var = $info.'002';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (ID, info1) VALUES (null ,'".$var."') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (info1) VALUES ('{$info}002')")or die(mysql_error());
```

It may not work only if your ID is set NOT NULL and it not set as autoincrement!

Comment: The page threw a syntax error... you have an ' too many maybe?